# How to remove the last character(s) from String in Dart

Tags: dart

This is what I came up with. If there is a better way, let me know.

Comment: Just curious, why do some people post their questions(that they already have answers to)  and supply an answer immediately ? @live-love

Comment: To share knowledge?

Comment: Ohh cool. I totally understand now. Thanks @live-love

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the last character from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438612/how-to-remove-the-last-character-from-a-string)

Comment: That's in java, I was looking for a dart solution and didn't find one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905889/how-to-get-the-last-n-characters-in-a-string-in-dart

Comment: Guess I missed it, I will try to close the question.

Answer (score 96):

Remove last character:

```
if (str != null && str.length > 0) {
  str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
}
```

Remove last 5 characters:

```
if (str != null && str.length >= 5) {
  str = str.substring(0, str.length - 5);
}
```

Comment: The test for `str.endsWith('x')` seems not relevant to the question. The question is "remove the last character(s)" not "remove the last character(s) if the string ends with x".

Comment: I think removing nothing from "Hi" in the 5-characters-case is rather surprising, but depends on the use case, I quess.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you have given would suffice the problem, just wanted to share this another way to remove the last element. Here I am using ***removeLast*** function provided by the dart library.

This function can be used on any list to remove the last element.

```
void main() {
  String x = "aaabcd";
  List<String> c = x.split(""); // ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  c.removeLast(); // ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
  print(c.join()); //aaabc
}
```